# Multiple projects in POP - how to handle inheritance?

Tags: java, selenium, inheritance, pageobjects

I have a problem how handle inheritance in my test project using Page Object Pattern. In our company we have one stable version of our web appliaction - something called Demo from which we copy ready modules. Kind like a base to other new versions of clients applications. They are in 90% all the same. So i think it would be great to make Base Page Objects Classes and in many projects inheritance from that classes.Sadly they are different in this 10% and I need to override xpaths in class fields. I have a problem when i inheritance from Base POP Class, make a field in child class, and method from parent class(Base POP Class) run on field in parent class not on child. Let show me your example. This is may parent class:

```
  public class BaseHomePage {

  @FindBy(xpath = "exampleXpath")
  protected WebElement profileButton;

  public BaseHomePage(WebDriver driver) {
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
  }

  public void goToProfile() {
    profileButton.click();
  }
```

and this is my child class:

```
public class HomePage extends BaseHomePage {

  @FindBy(xpath = "otherXpath")
  protected WebElement profileButton;

  public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
  }

  public void goToProfile() {
    profileButton.click();
  }
}
```

So problem is I need to use the same method goToProfile() in child class, because when i not method from parent call on field in parent class. I don't want to duplicate code and i search for answers but i'm not sure this is good use of POP in multiple projects. What i need to make it properly? Or maybe u would suggest me make it in another way? Thanks for help!

Comment: I don't fully understand your scenario, but it sounds like a lot of your problems could be solved by using an `interface`, and programming against that. If you want to be able to test the same things against different clients, with different selectors, I've seen a method using a factory to attach different maps(a class of selectors) to a page object based on the current client every time a page object was created. It worked, but IMO the return wasn't great since just automating the generic site had most of the value. You can always have a few specific cases for client specific functions.

Comment: But how i can use inerfaces to solve my problem? maybe u can tell more or give a name of pattern i should use?